HTMLに「OneTrust Cookie」を記述するとiframeが表示されなくなってしまう解決方法について
HTMLに「OneTrust Cookie」を記述するとiframeが表示されなくなってしまうため、解決方法を教えていただきたいです。
前提
・Youtubeの動画をiframeタグで埋め込んでおります。
・OneTrustのスクリプトをheadタグ直前に記述しております。
・OneTrustは私の方ではいじっておらず、共有されたものになります。（OneTrustの知見がございません。）
解決方法
OneTrust側の設定でiframeタグの表示非表示を設定できればそれが一番良いかと思うのですが、
何か他にも解決方法を思い当たる方がいらっしゃいましたら、教えていただけますと幸いです。
情報の不足等ございましたらご連絡ください。
よろしくお願いいたします。
